# SQOOP Server started but getting an error command not found

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, sqoop2

I am using ubuntu version 16.04

```
harsha@ubuntu:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

I was able to start sqoop server and sqoop shell but in the terminal when i type sqoop help or sqoop import it says command not found.

Error is

```
harsha@ubuntu:~$ sqoop help
sqoop: command not found
harsha@ubuntu:~$ sqoop -help
sqoop: command not found
harsha@ubuntu:~$ sqoop --help
sqoop: command not found
harsha@ubuntu:~$ sqoop
sqoop: command not found
```

Below command works Perfectly fine.

```
sqoop2-tool upgrade
sqoop2-tool verify
sqoop2-server start
sqoop2-server stop
sqoop2-shell
```

Here is the echo $PATH

```
/home/harsha/bin:/home/harsha/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:
/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/opt/hadoop-3.0.0/bin:
/opt/apache-flume-1.8.0-bin/bin:/opt/kafka_2.12-1.0.0/bin:
/opt/zookeeper-3.5.3-beta/bin:/usr/lib/sqoop-1.99.7-bin-hadoop200/bin:/usr/lib/sqoop-1.99.7-bin-hadoop200/conf:
```

Currently running process are

```
harsha@ubuntu:~$ jps
            6277 ResourceManager
            5814 DataNode
            90105 Jps
            37418 SqoopShell
            6395 NodeManager
            5694 NameNode
```

entries in  ~/.bashrc file are as follows

```
            export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
            export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
            #HADOOP HOME
            #export HADOOP_PREFIX=/opt/hadoop-3.0.0
            export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop-3.0.0
            export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
            #FLUME HOME
            export FLUME_HOME=/opt/apache-flume-1.8.0-bin
            export PATH=$PATH:$FLUME_HOME/bin
            #HADOOP HOME
            export KAFKA_HOME=/opt/kafka_2.12-1.0.0
            export PATH=$PATH:$KAFKA_HOME/bin
            #ZOOKEEPER HOME
            export ZOOKEEPER_HOME=/opt/zookeeper-3.5.3-beta
            export PATH=$PATH:$ZOOKEEPER_HOME/bin

            #SQOOP HOME
            export SQOOP_HOME=/usr/lib/sqoop-1.99.7-bin-hadoop200
            export SQOOP_CONF_DIR=$SQOOP_HOME/conf
            export SQOOP_CLASS_PATH=$SQOOP_HOME/server/lib
            export PATH=$PATH:$SQOOP_HOME/bin:$SQOOP_CONF_DIR:$SQOOP_CLASSPATH
```

It would be a great help if someone can help me out. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I am stuck at the moment any advise will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Locate for the sqoop command and add the path of the command to the $PATH variable.

```
locate sqoop
```